# Animating div from display none using opacity not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

### Problem

I have a login screen which will overlay the screen when the user clicks the login button. I initially set the login screen's opacity to 0 and display to none.

```
.login-screen {

    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #3472FF;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
}
```

In my Javascript I first show the div and then I set the opacity to 1:

```
 $(".login").on("click", function () {
        $(".login-screen").show(300, function () {
            $(".login-screen").css("opacity", "1");
        });
    });
```

However it does not transition smoothly like I would like. It does this strange thing ([see here](http://giphy.com/gifs/l0Iy00BqPQzEZB9qE)) where it resizes the login screen as it fades in. However, it fades out cleanly.

What I would like is to have the same clean fade in as my fade out. I don't want the divs in login screen to move, I just want them to fade in on click.

I also need to start with the `login-screen` `display: none`, since the `z-index: 1`, so that I can actually click on the login button. That is why after the `fadeOut()` I `hide()` the display.

If anyone could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

I've tried doing this in Javascript, but for some reason when I do that, the login screen does not show up at all when the login button is clicked.

```
$(".login").on("click", function () {
    $(".login-screen").show();
    $(".login-screen").fadeIn(300);
});

.login-screen{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div class="login-screen">
        <button class="close"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
        <form action="form.php" method="post">
            <div class="login-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" class="field submit" name="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

#### CSS

```
/*Remove auto styling*/

button:focus,
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.login-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #3472FF;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

.login-wrapper {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
}

input[type="text"],
.submit {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
    cursor: text;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 60%;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.submit {
    background-color: white;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid").on("mouseenter", ".grid-square", function () {
        $(this).find(".delete").fadeIn(100);
        $(this).find(".edit").fadeIn(100);
    });
    $(".grid").on("mouseleave", ".grid-square", function () {
        $(this).find(".delete").fadeOut(100);
        $(this).find(".edit").fadeOut(100);
    });
    $(".closeNavBtn").on("click", function () {
        $(".sidenav").css("width", "0vw");
    });
    $(".menu").on("click", function () {
        $(".sidenav").css("width", "250px");
    });
    $(".login").on("click", function () {
        $(".login-screen").show(300, function () {
            $(".login-screen").css("opacity", "1");
        });
    });
    $(".close").on("click", function () {
        $(".login-screen").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(".login-screen").hide();
        })
    });
});
```

### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid").on("mouseenter", ".grid-square", function () {
        $(this).find(".delete").fadeIn(100);
        $(this).find(".edit").fadeIn(100);
    });
    $(".grid").on("mouseleave", ".grid-square", function () {
        $(this).find(".delete").fadeOut(100);
        $(this).find(".edit").fadeOut(100);
    });
    $(".closeNavBtn").on("click", function () {
        $(".sidenav").css("width", "0vw");
    });
    $(".menu").on("click", function () {
        $(".sidenav").css("width", "250px");
    });
    $(".login").on("click", function () {
        $(".login-screen").show(300, function () {
            $(".login-screen").css("opacity", "1");
        });
    });
    $(".close").on("click", function () {
        $(".login-screen").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(".login-screen").hide();
        })
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500');

/*
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
*/


/*Color palette (for reference)*/

.color-lightest {
    color: #87ABFE;
    color: rgba(135, 171, 254, 1);
}

.color-light {
    color: #5C8EFF;
    color: rgba( 92, 142, 255, 1);
}

.color-main {
    color: #3472FF;
    color: rgba( 52, 114, 255, 1);
}

.color-dark {
    color: #135AFF;
    color: rgba( 19, 90, 255, 1);
}

.color-darkest {
    color: #0147E9;
    color: rgba( 1, 71, 233, 1);
}


/*General styling & remove auto styling*/

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.sidenav {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

button {
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba( 15, 72, 204, 0);
}


/*Side nav styling*/

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 70px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px 5px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px 5px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px 5px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.5);
}

.sidenav a,
.sidenav .closeNavBtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    display: block;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
    /* Standard syntax */
}

.sidenav .closeNavBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
}


/*Header styling*/

header {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 100vw;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

header {
    background: #3472FF;
    color: white;
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3472FF, #5C8EFF);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#3472FF, #5C8EFF);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3472FF, #5C8EFF);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3472FF, #5C8EFF);
    /* Standard syntax */
}

header .menu,
header .login {
    /*drag to top */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /*center menu icon on bar*/
    margin-top: 20px;
    /*formatting*/
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 52, 114, 255, 0);
    font-size: 1em;
}

header .menu {
    /*drag to left corner*/
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

header .login {
    /*drag to right corner*/
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i,400,400i');

/*General styling*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 10px 3% 0 3%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}

.row {
    display: block;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
}

.search,
.task {
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

div.element:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.element {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*Remove auto styling*/

button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #fafafb;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
}

button:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
    margin: 0;
}


/*General form  styling*/

input[type="text"],
select[name="course"],
input[name="due-date"] {
    background-color: #fafafb;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    border: none;
}

input[type="submit"],
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}


/*Datepicker styling*/


/*Set datepicker’s width, position it to the center and add drop shadow*/

.ui-datepicker {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    font: .7em 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .10);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .10);
    background-color: #fafafb;
}


/*Remove the default underline decoration from every anchor tag*/

.ui-datepicker a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*add 100% width for the table, so it will have the same maximum width as the wrapper above (i.e. widith: auto)*/

.ui-datepicker table {
    width: 100%;
}


/*style header*/

.ui-datepicker-header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #fafafb;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
}


/*center the Month position.*/

.ui-datepicker-title {
    text-align: center;
}


/*Set up arrows*/

.ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker-next {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 600%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/*Replace the Next and Prev text with the sprite arrow images and adjust arrow position*/

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;
    background-position: center 10px;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow_prev.png');
    /*Images created by me (Monica Ong)*/
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
    background-position: center 10px;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow_next.png')
    /*Images created by me (Monica Ong)*/
}


/*Set colors of day names*/

.ui-datepicker thead {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .7em;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #666666;
}


/*Style dates*/

.ui-datepicker tbody td {
    padding: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker tbody td {
    padding: 0;
}


/*Style default,  hover, and active state*/

.ui-datepicker td span,
.ui-datepicker td a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #666666;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
    background: #ededed;
}

.ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    color: #949496;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
    background: #666666;
    color: #efefef;
    position: relative;
    margin: -1px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td:first-child .ui-state-active {
    width: 29px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td:last-child .ui-state-active {
    width: 29px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last-child .ui-state-active {
    height: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*Search bar styling*/

.search {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.search-header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#search,
#show-all {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#search {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#show-all {
    font-size: 2em;
}

input[name="search"] {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 50px;
}

.search-header button[type="button"] {
    float: right;
}

.search-header #arrow {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.search-header .error {
    margin-left: 6%;
}

.search-details {
    margin-left: 4%;
}

.search-details h2 {
    display: inline;
}

.search-details .priority,
.search-details input[name="note"] {
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.search-details input[name="note"] {
    width: 85%;
}

.search-details .priority {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.search-details label {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/*Add task styling*/

input[name="title"] {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 2em;
}

select[name="course"],
input[name="due-date"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input[name="note"] {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    width: 100%;
}

input[name="due-date"] {
    width: 130px;
}

.error {
    color: #d11141;
}

.task-details h2 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.task-details label {
    margin-left: 20px;
}


/*Task styling*/

.task {
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.task:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.task-title {
    padding-top: 2.5%;
}

.checkbox,
button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}

.checkbox {
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

.task-info {
    float: right;
}

.task-info h2 {
    display: inline;
}

.task-info input[name="priority"] {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.task-info input[name="due-date"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.due-date {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

.priority {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.priority-high {
    color: #d11141;
}

.priority-medium {
    color: #ffc425;
}

.priority-low {
    color: #00aedb;
}

.task-details {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 4.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.task-date {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.note {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}


/*Footer*/

footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:link {
    color: #333333;
}

footer a:visited {
    color: #949496;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #949496;
}

footer a:active {
    color: #333333;
}

footer .icon-circle {
    font-size: .2em;
    color: #333333;
}

/*Remove auto styling*/

button:focus,
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.login-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #3472FF;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

.login-wrapper {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
}

input[type="text"],
.submit {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
    cursor: text;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 60%;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.submit {
    background-color: white;
    color: #3472FF;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
        <button class="closeNavBtn"><span class="icon-x"></span></button> <a href="photos.html">Photos</a> <a href="index.html">Albums</a> </div>
    <header>
        <button class="menu"><span class="icon-bars"></span></button> Albums
        <button class="login">Login</button>
    </header>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-square">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h1>Album Title</h1>
                <h2>Date</h2>
                <h2>Creator</h2></div>
            <button class="delete"><span class="icon-trash-can"></span></button>
            <button class="edit"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-square">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h1>Album Title</h1>
                <h2>Date</h2>
                <h2>Creator</h2></div>
            <button class="delete"><span class="icon-trash-can"></span></button>
            <button class="edit"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-square">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h1>Album Title</h1>
                <h2>Date</h2>
                <h2>Creator</h2></div>
            <button class="delete"><span class="icon-trash-can"></span></button>
            <button class="edit"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-square">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h1>Album Title</h1>
                <h2>Date</h2>
                <h2>Creator</h2></div>
            <button class="delete"><span class="icon-trash-can"></span></button>
            <button class="edit"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-square">
            <div class="grid-info">
                <h1>Album Title</h1>
                <h2>Date</h2>
                <h2>Creator</h2></div>
            <button class="delete"><span class="icon-trash-can"></span></button>
            <button class="edit"><span class="icon-pencil"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="add"><span class="icon-plus"></span></button>
    <footer></footer>
    <div class="login-screen">
        <button class="close"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
        <form action="form.php" method="post">
            <div class="login-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" class="field submit" name="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, one very slight logic error:

```
$(".login-screen").show(300, function () {
    $(".login-screen").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

You are setting the opacity inside the callback of a animation function, meaning the animation has completed and then you are setting the opacity.  Additionally, .show does not rely on opacity.  If, by default you want your menu to be invisible, use (and remove your opacity css):

```
display:none;
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to help me correct this error (i.e. show me what  I should write)? B/c previously I had `$(".login-screen").show();
        $(".login-screen").fadeIn(300);` with the `login-screen` display initially set to none and its opacity initially set to 0, but that didn't really work. I'm having trouble thinking of how to arrange my methods so that I can show the display and then fadeIn.

Comment: Okay, I'll look at your source.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/4eLccsq8/  your code is now updated... just a question... I don't see any "close" button.  Have you not written that yet? Or am I just blind?

Comment: it's b/c I hosted my close button icon on the cloud. I have linked it now in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4eLccsq8/3/. Question: it seems, however, that now the fadeOut() is acting abruptly even though it's the same duration as fadeIn()

Comment: Fixed, https://jsfiddle.net/4eLccsq8/3/ , removed "transition: opacity 0.5s ease;"